# Setting password idempotently for linux user in ansible

Tags: ansible

While attempting to manage users password using module `user` I'm getting password changed notice every single time when playbook is being executed and this behaviour does not depend on ansible version (tested on all major 2.0 - 2.5), target distribution (tested on stable CentOS, Debian and Ubuntu) or `update_password` option.

```
- name: This is in vault in real playbook of course
  set_fact:
    testuser_password : '123456'

- name: Manage test user
  user:
    name: testuser
    uid: 1001
    state: present
    password: "{{ testuser_password |password_hash('sha512')}}"
```

Task named "Manage test user" is always marked changed. To avoid that I'm using this weird construction

```
- name: This is in vault in real playbook of course
  set_fact:
    testuser_password : '123456'

- name: Check if user exists
  shell: "getent shadow testuser | awk -F: '{ print $2}'"
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  register: userexists

- name: Get salt for existing password
  shell: "getent shadow testuser | awk -F$ '{ print $3}'"
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  register: passwordsalt
  when: userexists.stdout != ""

- name: Encrypt local password with salt
  set_fact:
    localsaltedpass: "{{ testuser_password |password_hash('sha512', passwordsalt.stdout )}}"
  when: userexists.stdout != ""

- name: Update remote password
  user:
    name: "testuser"
    uid: 1001
    password: "{{ testuser_password |password_hash('sha512')}}"
  when: 
    - userexists.stdout != ""
    - userexists.stdout != localsaltedpass

- name: Create test user if it does not exist
  user:
    name: "testuser"
    uid: 1001
    state: present
    password: "{{ testuser_password |password_hash('sha512')}}"
  when: userexists.stdout == ""
```

While this approach solves the problem it does not look pretty well for me. Are there any ideas how to manage users passwords idempotently in a right way?

Comment: Why not store salt in your playbook/vault?

Comment: Man you are genius! Thanks a lot for your kick in a right direction.
Can you please answer the question so I be able to mark your answer as a correct one?

Comment: There's deleted answer from @techraf with the same idea. I'll mark it for undeletion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because salt is randomly regenerated each time one calls the `password_hash` filter. To make setting password idempotent, we have to keep salt and add it as a second parameter, like this:

```
- name: This should be stored in a vault in a real playbook of course
  set_fact:
    user_password: 'passw0rd'
    user_salt: 'some.salty.salt'

- name: Manage testuser
  user:
   name: "username"
   password: "{{ user_password | password_hash('sha512', user_salt) }}"
   state: present
   shell: /bin/bash
   update_password: on_create
```

Big thanks @[konstantin-suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov) for push in the right direction.

Also, please keep in mind, only alphanumerics, dots, and slashes can be used in salt, and for sha512 it should not be longer than 16 characters. Thank you @Peter De Zwart for this clarification.

Answer (score 1):

mind that special characters like underscores result in: {"msg": "crypt.crypt does not support 'sha512_crypt' algorithm"}
So for now, no underscores or other special chars in your salt!!!

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71107 mentions:

All of the hashing schemes available to password_hash only support characters from the regex range described by [./0-9A-Za-z]

Further than this, the salt length requirements are different:

md5: 0-8 characters
bcrypt: 22 characters
sha256: 0-16 characters
sha512: 0-16 characters